# Is there a way to "decorrelate" autocorrelation?

Tags: time-series, correlation, pca, autocorrelation, variance-decomposition

Just as how Principal Component Analysis tries to "decorrelate" the signals,

is there a way, given a time series potentially with autocorrelation with unknown lag length,

to transform that time series without autocorrelation?

Comment: There is: you can search whitening filter. Also if you ask this question on dsp.stackexchange you will get better answers: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/630/how-to-whiten-a-time-domain-signal

Comment: What do you mean by *to transform that time series without autocorrelation*? Do you mean *to transform that time series to another that has no autocorrelation*?

Answer (score 1):

You could fit a model, a long AR for instance, which can be seen as a filter which "whitens" the data: the residuals would be close to the innovations.

Since you mention PCA you might want to notice also that spectral analysis does something similar. It decomposes a time series in harmonic components mutually uncorrelated; but this is a different thing than what I think you are after.